# How to remove an unpushed outgoing commit in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I accidentally pushed a staged change in a new branch in Visual Studio 2017 to my local repository. It hasn't been pushed to the remote repository. I want to get rid of it but can't find a way to do this. I rebased from local master branch to the new branch. Then I deleted the new branch. But Outgoing Commits still shows it. How to delete it or revert it?

[image]

Answer (score 439):

Open the history tab in Team Explorer from the Branches tile (right-click your branch). Then in the history right-click the commit ***before*** the one you don't want to push, choose Reset. That will move the branch back to that commit and should get rid of the extra commit you made. **In order to reset before a given commit you thus have to select its parent.**

[image]

Depending on what you want to do with the changes choose **hard**, which will get rid of them locally. Or choose **soft** which will undo the commit but will leave your working directory with the changes in your discarded commit.

Comment: Worth putting in bold the part where ** you have to opt for RESET on the PARENT of the messed up commit ** - bizarrely VS2017, right after you do a commit, offers you a menu option that carries out the reset targetd at the commit you just did (a no-op) - I spent a few mins til I found your post and realised I should have Reset [To] the parent commit.. The menu option being "Reset" is slightly poorly worded - sounds like it will reset a particular commit == implying it should be used on that commit. If it were Reset To I reckon I would have understood it faster

Comment: (@JH) Thanks for the answer. .. atCJ  Thank you for the comment.  atJH  Thank you for bold-ing that part... atEverybody....that's the part I was stuck on....and I mean stuck.  #freedom

Comment: The naming is in line with how git calls the command. If you have edited files, those will get reset as well. If you have staged files, they will get reset as well. That's why there is a reset on the latest commit as well. It resets *to that* commit.

Comment: Notice: "before the one"

Comment: Just want to clarify that in VS2019 repo history window I had to mark the previous commit in the Local History to make the reset work properly.

Answer (score 150):

I could not find a single good answer that helped me get rid of this issue.

Let's say the name of branch, you accidentally committed changes to, is `master`. Following four simple steps proved like a world to me:

1. Go to Branches
2. Choose or create any branch other than `master`
3. Delete local/workspace version of `master`
4. Switch to master from `remotes/origin`

Comment: This is the answer that works, you don't have to push the `revert`

Comment: this works, but you're stuck when you only want to some(not all) specific commits from the Outgoing Commits.

Comment: @KatariaA you may have to take offline backups of the individual files and follow the process written above. Once done, you can replace your concerned files using the offline backups.

Comment: The simplest, best solution if you're happy losing all outgoing commits.

Comment: But how can you delete the local version of master?

Answer (score 133):

### TL;DR:

Use `git reset --soft HEAD~` in the cmd from the .sln folder

---

I was facing it today and was overwhelmed that `VSCode` suggests such thing, whereas its big brother `Visual Studio` doesn't.

Most of the answers weren't helpful; if I have more commits that were made before, losing them all would be frustrating.
Moreover, if `VSCode` does it in half a second, it shouldn't be complex.

Only [jessehouwing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115235/5762431) answer was the closest to a simple solution.

---

#### Assuming the undesired commit(s) was the last one to happen, Here is how I solved it:

Go to `Team Explorer` -> `Sync`.
There you'd see the all the commits. Press the `Actions` dropdown and `Open Command Prompt`

[image: undesired-commit-solved example]

You'll have the cmd window prompted, there write `git reset --soft HEAD~`.
If there are multiple undesired commits, add the amount after the `~` (i.e `git reset --soft HEAD~5`)

---

(If you're not using `git`, check colloquial usage).

I hope it will help, and hopefully in the next version VS team will add it builtin

Comment: Also, had to use Git tortoise (or such) to delete the commit. Couldn't do it from VS because the project file didn't have the new files that were added registered.

Comment: I had problems doing this from VS2019 but doing the command sorted it. Not really sure why VS had the problem.

Comment: Man, thanks a ton for this! Spent 20 minutes trying to achieve this from VS 2019, did it in 10 seconds from CLI.

Comment: I renamed my local branch and use the command git reset --soft HEAD~XX  where XX is number of unwanted push, that worked well for me. Then I synced and switched to desired branch. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using VS 2022 and Git in Jan 2023. I had 5 "upcoming" changes, ran this command 5 times and it worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options here to do that either to discard all your outgoing commits OR to undo specific commit ..

**1- Discard all your outgoing commits:**

To discard all your outgoing commits
For example if you have local branch named master from remote branch, You can:

1- Rename your local branch from master to anything so you can remove it.
2- Remove the renamed branch.
3- create new branch from the master

So now you have a new branch without your commits ..

**2- Undo specific commit:**
To undo specific commit you have to revert the unneeded by:

1- Double click on the unneeded commit.
[Double click on the unneeded commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cg8h.png)
2- Click on revert
[Click on revert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C34S3.png)

But FYI the reverted commit will appear in the history of your commits with the revert commit ..

Comment: Your first point, fixed my problem when I had the same issue as OP. Thx Mohammad! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming you have pushed most recent changes to the server:**

1. Close Visual Studio and delete your local copy of the project
2. Open Visual Studio, go to Team Explorer tab, click Manage Connections. (plug)
3. Click the dropdown arrow next to Manage Connections, Connect to a Project
4. Select the project, confirm the local path, and click the Connect button.

Once you reopen the project both commits and changes should be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Team Explorer tab then click Branches. In the branches select your branch from remotes/origin. For example, you want to reset your master branch. Right-click at the master branch in remotes/origin then select Reset then click Delete changes. This will reset your local branch and removes all locally committed changes.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is insane, but to me the easiest way is to:

1. Close Visual studio
2. Open in Visual code
3. Click undo commit on the commit
4. Close Visual code
5. Open again in Visual studio

Answer (score 2):

Another possibly insane answer, but worked. I say this only because Git confuses me daily.

For me the outgoing commit was properly merged through a PR to main, and shown correctly in the remote main branch, but my local main showed the same commit as an outgoing needing to be pushed.

- Can't Push to main...
- Reset (either hard or mixed) did nothing.

**My solution:** I deleted the local main branch and then re-checked out the remote main branch.

Comment: Without thinking so much.. this solution is best ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebase your local master branch onto your remote/origin master branch and resolve any conflicts in the process.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, is to click on "undo last commit", as I show in [screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s79f.png). I know you cant not delete a specific commit, however, I think its better this than create a new branch from main and clone localy your repostery again. You can always do a expense commit on your changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).